# Нормализация данных

Tags: python, mysql, sql, машинное-обучение, нормализация-данных

Задача состоит в нормализации(0-1) стакана приказов в биржевой торговле.

В стакане я могу видеть только 25 наилучших ценовых предложений, т.е. 25 приказов вида ASK и 25 приказов вида BID. Если я правильно понимаю то для нормализации нужно максимальное число в стакане(это будет 1), а минимальное(это будет 0), остальные числа это разброс между макс и мин значениями. Таким образом получается, что 1 всегда будет первый приказ в списке ASK, а 0 последний приказ в списке BID.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно нормализовать быстро меняющиеся данные такого рода? Нужно ли создавать отдельную БД для нормализации? И если да, то как?(Приказы быстро отменяются/появляются и непонятно какие данные надо записывать)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Описанная вами нормализация называется `Min-Max Scaling` и вычисляется по формуле:

```
z[i] = (x[i] - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x))
```

Соответственно самым быстрым способом скалирования быстроизменяющихся данных будет хранение трёх дополнительных значений (переменных):

- min_value
- max_value
- diff_max_min (max - min)

Расчёт скалированного значения:

```
z[i] = (x[i] - min_value) / diff_max_min
```

Далее по мере поступления новых значений обновлять эти три переменные при необходимости (если новое значение больше текущего максимума или меньше текущего минимума).

PS [Другие способы нормализации данных](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_(statistics))